# unusual relation, binary aspect

Tags: mysql, database-design, performance, relational-theory, denormalization

I have question very unusual for databases. I’m not a good English speaker, but good English reader :) so for explanation I’ll give you examples.

**Part1**

In MySQL, I have two tables with relations that I couldn't perform like primary-foreign key. Forward speaking, this is some "one to many" relation.
This is examples of tables:

```
#1 – States
ID      ConcVal    Type     Time
1        14        1        05:30
2        13        1        06:30
3        10        2        07:00
4        13        2        08:50
5        10        2        09:00
6        13        2        09:40
```

`ConcVal` is less or equal 15 (in binary **111**1) (actually I have 32 bit or even might more in future, but for simplify question it's only 4 bit). `ConcVal` - is something like superposition of `Descriptions` in binary. So `ConcVal` value may be the same for all `Types`, but meaning, that is described in second table, is different.

```
#2 - Descriptions
ID  Type    CVbits  Description
1   1       0       Some text for `type` 1
2   1       1       Some other text
3   1       2       Some other text
4   1       3       Some last text for type 1
5   2       0       Some text for type 2
…
8   2       3       Some last text for `type` 2
```

The relation between data makes by binary representation of `ConcVal` value: all bits that are “1” (excluding zero bit) relate to corteges of #2 by column `CVbits` and `Type`. `Type` in #1 and in #2 - the same thing. So:

ConcVal = 14 (**111**0) relates to corteges with CVbits {1;2;3};

ConcVal = 13 (**110**1) >> CVbits: {2;3};

ConcVal = 12 (**110**0) >> CVbits: {2;3}.

If talking about tables, the next one imaginary (actually, I did it) join can help understand my needs:

```
StateID     Type    ConcVal     (bin)       CVbits  DescrID
    1       1       14          (1110)      1       1
    1       1       14          (1110)      2       2
    1       1       14          (1110)      3       3
    …
    6       2       13          (1100)      2       6
    …
    6       2       13          (1100)      3       8
```

**Part2** (very small)

I know that logic described above better implement in front-end, but I want test how much can provide DBMS, so I wrote UDF, called `getCVbits`, which return string (call this bitorderstring) contained position numbers of bits in `ConcVal`, something like that `“,1,2,”,` and query left join with clause `“where getCVbits (a.ConcVal) LIKE concat(‘%,’b.CVbits,’,%’)”`. So, as you purpose, that query execute too long. Something near 1,2~2,0 sec for 300~3000 rows. I guess, UDF is too slow. But if you want, I think I can give you real query.

**Part3**

What if I will write insert and update triggers which are used `getCVbits` and calculate needed string. This string I can store in #1. That allows querying much faster, but goes against data normalization.

Question:

Q1. Is storing computed bitorderstring are good way or maybe let user wait a little? =) (I guess, result set will be much more than I tested)

Q2. How can I join `States` to `Descriptions` without LIKE operator in case using `getCVbits`? Actually, I can return from UDF anything I need.

Q3. Are another ways to implement “relation” between tables... data?

**UPDATED:**
So, like I promised, the results of 2 queries:

```
SELECT
    b.ID AS StatusID,
    b.Type as Type,
    b.CVTime AS CVTime,
    b.ConcVal AS ConcVal,
    CONV(b.ConcVal, 10, 2) AS BinStr,
    a.ID AS DescrID,
    a.CVbits AS CVbits,
    a.Description AS Description
FROM
    (Reasons a
    JOIN States b ON ((a.Type = b.Type)))
```

and **#1**

```
WHERE
    (a.CVbits <> 0)
        AND (a.CVbits <> 8)
        AND (a.CVbits <> 16)
        AND (1 << a.CVbits) & b.ConcVal
```

and **#2**

Like suggested Rick James:

> An easier (an faster at run-time) solution would be make `CVBits` an integer and store the binary-equivalent value (1, 2, 4, 8, 16) then join `ConcVal` to `CVBits` using a binary AND operator.

```
WHERE
    (a.CVbits <> 0)
        AND (a.CVbits <> 8)
        AND (a.CVbits <> 16)
        AND (a.CV & b.ConcVal)
```

Not so different at ~4280 rows returned (duration/fetch):

```
#1 (1<<CVbits & ConcVal)    #2 (CV & ConcVal)
0.016 sec / 0.421 sec       0.015 sec / 0.687 sec
0.016 sec / 0.156 sec       0.000 sec / 0.296 sec
0.031 sec / 0.234 sec       0.016 sec / 0.171 sec
0.016 sec / 0.218 sec       0.016 sec / 0.359 sec
0.016 sec / 0.172 sec       0.016 sec / 0.125 sec
```

instead (1.794 sec / 78.235) sec when i use UDF and `LIKE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WHERE (1 << CVbits) & ConcVal
  AND CVbits != 0    -- (to "exclude the zero bit")
```

Comment: thanks a lot, man. I guess it's what I need. I will test at work

Comment: all my troubles seems so far away=). It works with little change: `1 << (4-CVbits)` goes to `1 << CVbits`. Thanks you very much. Would you edit answer to choose it as Answered?

Comment: Hmmm...  Now for a time machine to go back and figure out why I did the expression wrong.  :(

Comment: for zero bit not necessary add ' CVbit != 0' if  no values in #2 table. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

> Q1. Is storing computed bitorderstring are good way or maybe let user wait a little? =) (I guess, result set will be much more than I tested)

MySQL supports columns of type bit.  These only use one bit each, in sets of 8, as you would expect.  This will give the same disk and memory density as you're currently getting, but with much easier query writing.

> Q2. How can I join States to Descriptions without LIKE operator in case using getCVbits? Actually, I can return from UDF anything I need.

@Rick Has it: you need to do binary maths on `tblDescriptions.CVbits`.  An easier (an faster at run-time) solution would be make `CVBits` an integer and store the binary-equivalent value (1, 2, 4, 8, 16) then join `ConcVal` to `CVBits` using a binary AND operator.

> Q3. Are another ways to implement “relation” between tables... data?

Yes.  Normalise your design.  `ConcVal` breaks first normal form because it holds many values.  Create a new table which contains only `tblStates.ID` and `tblDescriptions.ID`.

And please, please stop prefixing your table names with 'tbl'.

Comment: Thanks for response. Storing `bitorderstring` i needed just to join with `LIKE` in my previous "solution". Now, it's not necessary. About normalization - I agree with you, but I didn't say that ConcVal is raw input and user need to pick up right bit, which will store in another table. So, i guess, my Q3 not actually almost right. An integer that store binary-equivalent value makes sense! I guess, it's second solution. I'll test perfomance and post here.

Comment: @brz I suggest you also test the last suggestion ("*Normalize ...*")

Comment: @ypercube i did tests, but was not so much records so no so big difference between queries